# How to auto close modal window in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

I tried this but my program crashed.

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [modalWindow orderOut:self];
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
```

Comment: How did it crash? Putting the crash report here would be helpful for us to figure out the problem.

Comment: Specific run log message + backtrace, please.

Comment: It didn't responding and the cursor turned into twirling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, modalWindow is not pointing to a valid object. That's the only obvious thing that would crash in those two lines.  You should be able to use the debugger to find out more about why it's crashing before asking for help.

Comment: Specifically, it is pointing to an invalid (deceased) object. `nil` isn't a valid object, either, but sending a message to it will not cause a crash.

Comment: I unchecked "Release When Closed" option on Interface Builder then it's running fine.Thanks.